# No visible @interface for 'pushnotifications' decalre the selector 'setdevicetoken:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, xcode12

I am new at iOS, I'm using Pusher for notifications.

I have no idea how to fix this error.

```
no visible @interface for 'pushnotifications' decalre the selector 'setdevicetoken:'

no visible @interface for 'pushnotifications' decalre the selector 'handleNotification:'
```

Here is my code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <PushNotifications/PushNotifications.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

// Add the following as a new method to AppDelegate.m
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  NSLog(@"Registered for remote with token: %@", deviceToken);
  [[PushNotifications alloc] setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  [[PushNotifications alloc] handleNotification:userInfo];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Remote notification support is unavailable due to error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

@end
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks all.

Comment: `[[PushNotifications alloc] handleNotification:userInfo];`, the `alloc` + direct call seems strange. Are you using `https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-swift`? It should be the `shared`, not `alloc`. See sample code: https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-swift/blob/master/push-notifications-objc/push-notifications-objc/AppDelegate.m

Comment: thats works! great! thanks for the sample